# Celery: Is it better to store task results in MySQL or Redis?

Tags: python, mysql, django, redis, celery

Currently I am using celery to build a scheduled database synchronization feature, which periodically fetch data from multiple databases. If I want to store the task results, would the performance be better if I store them in Redis instead of a RDB like MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

Performance-wise it's probably going to be Redis but performance questions are almost always nuance based.

Redis stores lists of data with no requirement for them to relate to one another so is extremely fast when you don't need to use SQL type queries against the data it contains.

Comment: Thanks, so generally for data like celery task results, there shouldn't be SQL type queries needed right?

Comment: Unless you're doing something crazy, not with celery itself for sure.

Comment: What if I want long term storage about those results? Then I guess a RDB would be a more ideal choice?